# Projection of a rectangle onto a sphere

Tags: 3d, projective-geometry

I have a rectangle of side lengths $x,y$ projected onto a sphere, with arc lengths $x',y'$ and arc angles $\phi,\theta$. If I have $x,y$, how can I derive $\phi,\theta$? I was able to accomplish the opposite via $x = r\cdot\theta\cos\frac\phi2$ and $y = r\cdot\phi\cdot\cos\frac\theta2$

[image]

Comment: Consider two cross sections, one verticle and one horizontal. You'll end up with two separate arc length calculations, which independently are pretty easy.

Comment: @DonThousand  I have no doubt I'm being dumb.. but I can't separate them.. x' is dependent on y', and vice-versa?

Comment: I never said any such thing :) Think about the cross sections I proposed.

Comment: @DonThousand Thank you for your attention, I'm embarrassed to present what is probably such a lowly problem on this site ( I can't even insert appropriate notation).. I've expanded the OP to describe the 'dependency'  I can't get round.

Comment: @Again, I'm not asking for any apologies, just trying to guide you in the right direction. So I'm not sure what you want here. Your equations look good to me

Comment: @DonThousand (I know I'm due a self-administered face-slap soon ;) ) The problem is I can't solve for theta without knowing phi, and I can't solve for phi without knowing theta..

Comment: Ah so that is your question. Let me edit to make it clear that is what you are asking.

Comment: For this case, I would instead use law of cosines. Note that $x^2=r^2+r^2-2r^2\cos\theta$ which more simply is written as $\frac xr =\sqrt{2\cdot(1-\cos\theta)}$.

Comment: @DonThousand Thank you. I'll have another look later today.